Split the data of the particular column from the file using unix command
We have requirement here to split file based on colum 3
on 3rd column we have 9 unique values based on this we need split into 2 files one
contain 4 another file contain remaining 5 (its based on no of unique values in 3 column if we have 20 unique values we will split into 10 & 10 )
and header should be added on both files
We will count the no of unique values with this cmd
awk -F'|' '{print $3}' inputfile.txt | uniq

after counting how to put into 2 files
half of the count should in one file, remaining in another file
Please advise a script/cmd to that
Input file
Header|Name|date
 c|125|ER
 de|126|ER
 fr|127|ER
 xe|128|ER
 A|123|MR
 b|124|MR
 c|125|XR
 de|126|YR
 fr|127|ZR
 xe|128|NR
 A|123|BR
 b|124|BR
 c|125|CR
 de|126|CR
 fr|127|DR
 xe|128|DR
 A|123|ER
 b|124|ER

Output file 1
Header |Name | date
 c|125|ER
 de|126|ER
 fr|127|ER
 xe|128|ER
 A|123|ER
 b|124|ER
 A|123|MR
 b|124|MR
 c|125|XR
 de|126|YR
 fr|127|ZR

output file 2
Header|Name|date
xe|128|NR
 A|123|BR
 b|124|BR
 c|125|CR
 de|126|CR
 fr|127|DR
 xe|128|DR


You've given us your data and your existing code, but what's the specific problem with your code you need our help to solve?

BTW, you can probably implement everything just in awk with no sort or uniq at all. awk supports a map/dictionary type; it has everything you need for counters, and it also can write multiple output files.

BTW, put a line with three backticks and nothing else above and below each data section to prevent it from being formatted as Markdown. (I did this for you in an edit but you overwrote it).

Create an associative array whose keys are the $3 values, and values are the alternating filenames. Then write each line to the filename corresponding to the appropriate array entry.

Exactly what is the logic that should be used to determine what content goes in which of the output files, and what the ordering within those files are? (Your example has "output file 2" sorted by the header field, but output file 1 is not in an obviously consistent sort order).

Beyond that, though... we do expect you to be asking about a single narrow, specific problem you encountered while writing your own program for a purpose; we're here to solve well-defined questions about problems you encountered while writing your own code, not to write arbitrary software to spec.

@CharlesDuffy It looks like the assignments of $3 values to files are arbitrary, so long as they're split evenly.

Do you care about whitespace?  If you use -F'|', then whitespace becomes significant and a|b|   c|d has a different 3rd column than a|b|c|d.

I don't understand why the MR weren't outputted in output_file_1

MR can be in first file also not a problem

Now i have updated the example , need to split the file based on 3rd column

awk -F'|' '
  NR>FNR { exit }
  NR==1 {
    n=ARGC-2
    if (n<1) { print "not enough output files"; exit }
    for (i=2; i<ARGC; i++) print >ARGV[i]
    next        
  }
  { print >ARGV[ $3 in seen ? seen[$3] : ( seen[$3]=(++i%n)+2 ) ] }
' inputfile outputfile1 outputfile2

Pass the input file and one or more output filenames as arguments in ARGV. (Output files will have indices 2, 3, ..., ARGC-1.)

NR>FNR - no longer reading input file, so finished
NR==1 - save number of output files as n for later use (abort if n < 1) then write header to every output file
on every following input line:

if $3 has already been seen, select its associated output file (i.e. ARGV[seen[$3]])
else, use modular arithmetic on a counter to associate $3 with index of "next" output file, and select that
print the line to the selected file



The parentheses around the assignment to seen[$3] avoids misparsing by the busybox version of awk.
Works for any (small) positive number of output files (if there are too many, awk will run out of filehandles).
For your sample input, this code will split as:
outputfile1 :
Header|Name|date
 A|123|MR
 b|124|MR
 de|126|YR
 xe|128|NR
 c|125|CR
 de|126|CR

outputfile2 :
Header|Name|date
 c|125|ER
 de|126|ER
 fr|127|ER
 xe|128|ER
 c|125|XR
 fr|127|ZR
 A|123|BR
 b|124|BR
 fr|127|DR
 xe|128|DR
 A|123|ER
 b|124|ER

With 3 output files, it gives:
Header|Name|date
 c|125|ER
 de|126|ER
 fr|127|ER
 xe|128|ER
 de|126|YR
 A|123|BR
 b|124|BR
 A|123|ER
 b|124|ER

Header|Name|date
 A|123|MR
 b|124|MR
 fr|127|ZR
 c|125|CR
 de|126|CR

Header|Name|date
 c|125|XR
 xe|128|NR
 fr|127|DR
 xe|128|DR


Nice idea to put the output files in argument +1
